# HDFS space consumed: "hdfs dfs -du /" vs "hdfs dfsadmin -report"

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Which tool is the right one to measure HDFS space consumed?

When I sum up the output of "hdfs dfs -du /" I always get less amount of space consumed compared to "hdfs dfsadmin -report" ("DFS Used" line). Is there data that du does not take into account?

Answer (score 6):

Hadoop file systems provides a relabel storage, by putting a copy of data to several nodes. The number  of copies is replication factor, usually it is greate then one.

Command `hdfs dfs -du /` shows space consume your data without replications.

Command `hdfs dfsadmin -report` (line DFS Used) shows actual disk usage, taking into account data replication. So it should be several times bigger when number getting from `dfs -ud` command.

Comment: "hdfs dfs -du" in later hadoop versions outputs both (size without and with replication)

Comment: Why `dfs -du -s` (bytes) and `hdfs dfs -count -v` (supposeed same bytes at CONTENT_SIZE field) are (near but) **not the same** values?

Answer (score 2):

How HDFS Storage works in brief:

```
Let say replication factor = 3 (default) 
Data file size = 10GB (i.e xyz.log)
HDFS will take 10x3 = 30GB to store that file
```

Depending on the type of command you use, you will get different values for space occupied by HDFS (10GB vs 30GB)

If you are on latest version of Hadoop, try the following command. In my case this works very well on Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP) 2.3.* and above. This should also work on cloudera's latest platform.

```
hadoop fs -count -q -h -v /path/to/directory
```

(-q = quota, -h = human readable values, -v = verbose)

This command will show the following fields in the output. 
QUOTA  REMAINING_QUOTA     SPACE_QUOTA  REMAINING_SPACE_QUOTA    DIR_COUNT  FILE_COUNT      CONTENT_SIZE FILE_NAME

Where

```
CONTENT_SIZE = real file size without replication (10GB) and 
SPACE_QUOTA = space occupied in HDFS to save the file (30GB)
```

Notes:
Control replication factor here: Modify "dfs.replication" property found in hdfs-site.xml file under conf/ dir of default hadoop installation directory). Changing this using Ambari/Cloudera Manager is recommended if you have multinode cluster.

There are other commands to check storage space. E.G hadoop fsck, hadoop dfs -dus,

Comment: Why `dfs -du -s path1` (bytes) and `hdfs dfs -count -v path1` (supposeed same bytes at CONTENT_SIZE field) are (near but) **not the same** values?

Comment: `SPACE_QUOTA` doesn't show the space occupied in HDFS, but the value of the quota defined. You should substruct `REM_SPACE_QUOTA` from `SPACE_QUOTA` to get the space occupied.