# “hdfs dfs -du” vs “hdfs dfs -count”, differences on expecting same results

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Why [`hdfs  dfs -du -s`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#du)   and [`hdfs dfs -count -v`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#count) (supposeed same bytes at CONTENT_SIZE field) are (near but) **not the same** values?

---

### Example

```sh
# at user1@borderNode1
hdfs dfs -count -v  "hdfs://XYZ/apps/hive/warehouse/p_xx_db.db"
#   DIR_COUNT   FILE_COUNT       CONTENT_SIZE PATHNAME
#        9087      1610048    141186781009632 hdfs://XYZ/apps/hive/warehouse/p_xx_db.db
hdfs dfs -du -s  "hdfs://XYZ/apps/hive/warehouse/p_xx_db.db"
#141186781010380  hdfs://XYZ/apps/hive/warehouse/p_xx_db.db
```

The value 141186781009632 is not 141186781010380.

The difference `141186781010380-141186781009632=748` is less tham the blocksize (134217728 in the example)... so, perhaps, one is exact and other not, but I not see this kind of documentation on Hadoop.

---

PS: no clues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33517658/287948) neither at guide,

- `hdfs dfs -count`: "Count the number of ... bytes under the directory... output column CONTENT_SIZE".
- `dfs -du`: "Displays sizes files... contained in the given directory".

Guide say only that both are number of  bytes contained  under the directory.

Comment: What if you add `-x` option?

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007! I will test `hdfs dfs -du -x`  next week.  The guide say *"The -x option will exclude snapshots from the result calculation. Without the -x option (default), the result is always calculated from all INodes, including all snapshots under the given path"*. I am supposing that the most stable (to avoid day by day oscilations) is excluding snapshots, is it?

Comment: I'm not completely sure how much snapshots take up in storage, but it's worth taking a look at. I do know I've had a similar issues with regular Linux `du` showing me open file handles for deleted files

Comment: Sorry @cricket_007, I am using Hadoop version 2.7.3, where [`du -x` not exists](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#du)... But it is a good clue: seems that `-x` was implemented to solve the problem of this question.