# HDFS: Total size of subdirectories is smaller than the parent directory?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Hi I'm using HDFS but interestingly I found my parent dir's size is greater than the total size of its subdirs. This is strange to me. Does anyone know why? Thanks! Please see the following cli:

```
user@machine-cli-001:~$ hdfs dfs -du -h -s /apps/xxx/yyy/zzz/20230625
10.9 G  /apps/xxx/yyy/zzz/20230625
user@machine-cli-001:~$ hdfs dfs -du -h -s /apps/xxx/yyy/zzz/20230625/*
4.8 G  /apps/xxx/yyy/zzz/20230625/regular_data_folder
631.8 M  /apps/xxx/yyy/zzz/20230625/special_data_folder
```

As you see, 4.8G + 631.8M < 10.9G. I'm not a Hadoop cluster maintainer but just a user. So there could be something the admin team has done behind the scene. However I want to make sure I didn't  screw up something from my end.

Comment: Can you try it with 'hdfs dfs -count -h'

Comment: @CompEng thanks, `hdfs dfs -count -h` did give me reasonable results, but how come it differ from `hdfs dfs -du -h`? I can't tell the reason

Comment: Have you tried to run `hdfs dfs -du -s -h -x ...` and see if it reconciles the difference?

Answer (score 1):

You can kook [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59789608/hdfs-dfs-du-vs-hdfs-dfs-count-differences-on-expecting-same-results) to find the difference between `-du` and `-count` and also `-x` option

By the way you can use `hdfs dfs -count -h`