# Difference between `hadoop fs -du` and `hadoop fs -df` in Dataproc

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I use a long-lived Google Cloud Dataproc single-node cluster, to run a Spark streaming job. I note that the reported used HDFS capacity never decrease. Currently, more than 3GB are used.
However, when I connect to the instance, used HDFS capacity may vary depending on the method I use:

```bash
# hdfs dfsadmin -report -help
Configured Capacity: 31460429824 (29.30 GB)
Present Capacity: 8027910788 (7.48 GB)
DFS Remaining: 4038037504 (3.76 GB)
DFS Used: 3989873284 (3.72 GB)
DFS Used%: 49.70%
Replicated Blocks:
        Under replicated blocks: 0
        Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
        Missing blocks: 0
        Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
        Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
        Pending deletion blocks: 0
Erasure Coded Block Groups: 
        Low redundancy block groups: 0
        Block groups with corrupt internal blocks: 0
        Missing block groups: 0
        Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
        Pending deletion blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 10.10.0.46:9866 (*************.**************.******)
Hostname: *************.**************.******
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 31460429824 (29.30 GB)
DFS Used: 3989873284 (3.72 GB)
Non DFS Used: 22026657148 (20.51 GB)
DFS Remaining: 4038037504 (3.76 GB)
DFS Used%: 12.68%
DFS Remaining%: 12.84%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 0
Last contact: Fri Dec 08 07:34:55 UTC 2023
Last Block Report: Fri Dec 08 03:40:22 UTC 2023
Num of Blocks: 461115

# hdfs dfs -df -h
Filesystem                              Size   Used  Available  Use%
hdfs://******                         29.3 G  3.7 G      3.7 G   13%

# hdfs dfs -du -s -h /
231.7 M  231.7 M  /

# hadoop fs -count -q -h -v /
       QUOTA       REM_QUOTA     SPACE_QUOTA REM_SPACE_QUOTA    DIR_COUNT   FILE_COUNT       CONTENT_SIZE PATHNAME
       8.0 E           8.0 E            none             inf       15.5 K      450.4 K            231.8 M /

# hdfs dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota 10G /
# hdfs dfs -count -q -h -v /
       QUOTA       REM_QUOTA     SPACE_QUOTA REM_SPACE_QUOTA    DIR_COUNT   FILE_COUNT       CONTENT_SIZE PATHNAME
       8.0 E           8.0 E            10 G           9.8 G       15.5 K      450.7 K            231.9 M /
# hdfs dfsadmin -clrSpaceQuota /
```

So, what I understand from all of these stuffs:

- The replication factor seems to be 1 (this make sense as I am on a single node cluster, so not very useful to replicate on the same machine), and so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33518390/4373898) doesn't apply
- Most of the disk space is used by non-HDFS content (hello syslog, journald, and hdfs logs)
- Only ~250MB seems to be reachable through HDFS
- But it consumes +3.7GB of disk space.

How can you explain the difference between `df` and `du` reported sizes ? How can I make them coherent ?

Kind,
Alexis.

Comment: They are two different commands which report different things. It's not just on Hadoop; see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45771/df-vs-du-why-so-much-difference

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the link, I learned something. However, I don't see how it apply to HDFS (which should not suffer from the below block size files accounting or superblock stuff (is there an equivalent in HDFS world?)). Moreover I would agree on some "minor" differences (some kB or MB), but here there is more than 3GB of difference !! Anyway, is there an "easy" way to make them agree, closing deleted files or such things ?

Comment: YARN/HDFS can allocate files on the worker nodes... Closing them should help. I think you can use `lsof` for finding the deleted, but still open files, but I forget the command

Comment: This answer claims the difference is due to partial blocks in HDFS taking as much space as a full block. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/space-used-in-hdfs-is-different-from-free-space/td-p/196064